# need to fix my script - cmds.setKeyframe error

Tags: python, maya, keyframe

I need to fix my script, just wrote a grab_animation function, a save_animation function, and finally my restore_animation.

Here it is.

```
def restore_animation(path, animation_dictionary=None):
     dict_file = open(path, 'rb')           
     dict_anim_pkld = pickle.load(dict_file)
     dict_file.close() 

     for each_frame in dict_anim_pkld:
         cmds.currentTime(each_frame)

         for each_obj in dict_anim_pkld[each_frame]:
             for each_attr in dict_anim_pkld[each_frame][each_obj]:
                  cmds.setKeyframe('{0}.{1}'.format(each_obj,each_attr))
                  cmds.setAttr ('{0}.{1}'.format(each_obj,each_attr), dict_anim_pkld[each_frame][each_obj][each_attr]['value'])
```

The problem is, the function works great but it only restore the values of the animation but it doesn't set the keys for every keyframe.
i know that the command i have to implement is `cmds.setKeyframe` but after a lot of tests it doesn't work yet. Who can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Well one problem could be that you're passing in both the object and the attribute name into cmds.setKeyframe(). Normally object attributes return the entire name. i.e. "polyCube1.translateX", so when you pipe in `cmds.setKeyframe('{0}.{1}'.format(each_obj,each_attr))` it's really telling it `cmds.setKeyframe('polyCube1.polyCube1.translateX')`. Same thing for your `cmds.setAttr()`.

Comment: mmm not really, like i wrote it works fine but it sets only the values.. i want that for every keyframe it setKeyframe with the appropriate value

Comment: Perhaps reversing the key and set commands might prove useful. I just tried recreating it and the problem you stated occurred, then I flipped them and it worked fine. I just tested it on a cube. Your code looks pretty solid other than that so if that doesn't work it might just be a data input issue from your file.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're not setting the value in your setKeyframe call.  The reason @argiri's solution worked is that he's setting the attribute then calling setKeyframe with no args, which keys the current value.  I think you want:

```
cmds.setKeyframe('{0}.{1}'.format(each_obj,each_attr), 
    v=dict_anim_pkld[each_frame][each_obj][each_attr]['value'], 
    t=each_frame)
```

assuming dict_anim_pkld[each_frame][each_obj][each_attr]['value'] is how you're storing the old value and each_frame is a time value Maya can recognize